# Spring Service name conflicting with Interface name

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have an Interface name

```
public interface ScoreDao {

   public int storeScore(OverallScore overallScore);

   public void storeIndividualScore(ScoreTO scoreTO);
}
```

The implementation class is like below

```
@Repository("scoreDao")
public class ScoreDaoImpl implements ScoreDao {
   @Override
   public int storeScore(OverallScore overallScore) {
      //Implementation 
   }
   @Override
   public void storeIndividualScore(ScoreTO scoreTO){
       //Implementation
   }
}
```

The caller is using the service like below

```
@Service("scoreService")
public class scoreServiceImpl implements IScoreService {
   @Autowired
   private ScoreDao scoreDao;

   @Override
   public int storeScore(OverallScore overallScore) {
      return scoreDao.storeOverallScore(overallScore);
   }

   @Override
   public void storeIndividualScore(ScoreTO scoreTO) {
      scoreDao.storeIndividualScore(scoreTO);
   }
}
```

I'm using spring 4.x, while deploying I'm getting bean conflict error as below.

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
>   Annotation-specified bean name 'ScoreDao' for bean class [ScoreDao]
>   conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name
>   and class [ScoreDaoImpl]

When I change the interface name to IScoreDao, it is working. Is it because of service name @Repository("scoreDao") same as Interface name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is **Yes**,it was due to that you have an interface called `ScoreDao` and you make the implementation of it as `@Repository("scoreDao")`

two ways to solve it:

1. Rename `ScoreDao` to other name
2. Change `@Repository("scoreDao")` to `@Repository` so that it will use the default name

Comment: @samba sorry,I can not fully understand what you replied just now

Comment: Even though, if I don't specify the name inside Repository and use like blow still getting an error
Repository
 public class ScoreDaoImpl implements ScoreDao {}

Autowired
private ScoreDao scoreDao;
When I use like that, getting below error

No qualifying bean of type [ScoreDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: scoreDaoImpl,scoreDao

Comment: @samba,it's weird,can you add your xml configuration code?

Answer (score 0):

there is one another solution mention @Repository on your interface so that you don't need to mention on your implementation class because you implements that interface. so it creates the bean automatically with the interface name.